# $Z$ has no accumulation point in $C$?

Tags: real-analysis

We say that $z_0$ is an accumulation point in a domain $D$ if there exists a sequence $(z_n)_{n\in N}\subset D$ s.t $z_n$ converges to $z_0$. I would like to know, using this definition, why $\Bbb Z$ has no accumulation point in $\Bbb C$ ?

Comment: a small correction: $(z_n)_{n\in N}\subset D\setminus \{z_0\}$. does it make sense now?

Comment: All points of $\mathbb Z$ remain at distance at least $1$ of $z_0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong definition. It should be: $z_0$ is an accumulation point of a domain $D$ if there exists a sequence $(z_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of elements of $D\setminus\{z_0\}$ such that $z_n$ converges to $z_0$. With this definition, $\Bbb Z$ has no accumulation points in $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Is this because any point in $\Bbb Z$ is a complex number ?

Comment: No. Not even close. If that was true, then no subset of $\Bbb C$ would have accumulation points, right?

Answer (score 0):

Your definition is simply wrong.

If $z_n = (2 + \frac 1n) - \frac 1{2n}i$ then $z_n \to 2 \in \mathbb Z$ and so $2$ is, by your definition "a limit point in $\mathbb C$".

I think the correct definition is

> In a domain $D$, the point $a$, is a limit point **of** a set $M$, if there is a sequence of points $z_n\in M$ *and such that none of the $z_n = a$* where $z_n \to a$.

With that definition, the set $\mathbb Z$ doesn't have any limit points in *any* domain (with the Euclidean metric).

That is because integers are always at least $1$ away from each other.  So any sequence *of integers* that converge, that is "eventually get close to a value", can only be if the sequence eventually ends with an infinite repeat of one integer that is value it converges to.

More formally:

Consider this suppose $a\in \mathbb C$ is a limit point of $\mathbb Z$.  That means there exists $\{z_k\}\subset \mathbb Z$ so that $\lim_{n\to \infty} z_n = a$.  Thatn means that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there we be a point where $|z_n - a| < \epsilon$ for all $n$ larger than a certain value.

Let $\epsilon = \frac 14$  If $|z_n - a| < \frac 14$ then $a-\frac 14 < z_n < a+\frac 14$.  But $z_n$ is an integer and there is at *most* one integer in that interval.  But these must be true of *all* epsilon no matter how small, so the only way we can have some $z_n$ where $a-\epsilon < z_n < a+\epsilon$ for *all* epsilon is if $a = z_n$ for some $z_n$.

So $\lim_{n\to \infty} z_n = a$ means that $a\in \{z_n\}$ so $a = z_N$ for some $N$ and that for all $n > N$ we have all such $z_n = a$.

But the definition of a limit point is that *none* of the terms in a sequence are $a$ and here we have an *infinite* number of terms of the sequence being $a$.

So there is no limit point of $\mathbb Z$ in *any* domain (assuming we are using the Euclidean metric)